# configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables?

Tags: kannel

When I configured the Kannel softwre I got the following problem:

```
checking for C compiler default output file name...
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

The config.log file is as follows:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.62.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/kannel

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = sreeni9
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 1.7.1(0.218/5/3)
uname -s = CYGWIN_NT-5.1
uname -v = 2009-12-07 11:48

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = i686
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/WinAVR-20100110/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/WinAVR-20100110/utils/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32
PATH: /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS
PATH: /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem
PATH: /cygdrive/c/WinAVR-20100110/avr/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/WinAVR-20100110/utils/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/WinAVR-20100110/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/libxml2-2.6.30+.win32/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_16/bin
PATH: .


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2053: checking build system type
configure:2071: result: i686-pc-cygwin
configure:2093: checking host system type
configure:2108: result: i686-pc-cygwin
configure:2180: checking for gcc
configure:2196: found /cygdrive/c/WinAVR-20100110/avr/bin/gcc
configure:2207: result: gcc
configure:2445: checking for C compiler version
configure:2453: gcc --version >&5
gcc.exe (WinAVR 20100110) 4.3.3
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2457: $? = 0
configure:2464: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: avr
Configured with: ../gcc-4.3.3/configure --enable-win32-registry=WinAVR-20100110 --with-gmp=/usr/local --with-mpfr=/usr/local --prefix=/c/WinAVR --target=avr --enable-languages=c,c++,objc --with-dwarf2 --enable-doc --disable-shared --disable-libada --disable-libssp --disable-nls --with-pkgversion='WinAVR 20100110' --with-bugurl='URL:http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?atid=520074&group_id=68108&func=browse'
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.3.3 (WinAVR 20100110) 
configure:2468: $? = 0
configure:2475: gcc -V >&5
gcc.exe: '-V' option must have argument
configure:2479: $? = 1
configure:2502: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2524: gcc    conftest.c  >&5

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
configure:2528: $? = 3
configure:2566: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define GW_NAME "Kannel"
| #define GW_VERSION "1.4.3"
| #define VERSION "1.4.3"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2573: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=i686-pc-cygwin
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_YACC_set=
ac_cv_env_YACC_value=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=i686-pc-cygwin
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
CC='gcc'
CFLAGS=''
CONVERT=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DOCDRAFTS=''
DOCSTARGET=''
DVIPS=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
EXE_EXT=''
FIG2DEV=''
GREP=''
GW_VERSION=''
HTML_DSL=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
JADE=''
JADETEX=''
LDFLAGS=''
LEX=''
LEXLIB=''
LEX_OUTPUT_ROOT=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MYSQL_CONFIG=''
OBJEXT=''
OPENSSL=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PCRE_CONFIG=''
PDFJADETEX=''
PERL=''
PGSQL_CONFIG=''
PKGADD_NAME='Kannel - WAP and SMS gateway'
PKGADD_PKG='KANNELgateway'
PKGADD_VENDOR='www.kannel.org'
RANLIB=''
SDB_CONFIG=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SIZEOF_INT=''
SIZEOF_LONG=''
SIZEOF_LONG_LONG=''
SIZEOF_SHORT=''
SQLITE3=''
SQLITE=''
STARTSTOPDAEMONSRC=''
SUFFIX=''
TEX_DSL=''
VERSION='1.4.3'
XML_CONFIG=''
YACC=''
YFLAGS=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='i686-pc-cygwin'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='i686'
build_os='cygwin'
build_vendor='pc'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${prefix}/share/doc/kannel'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='i686-pc-cygwin'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='i686'
host_os='cygwin'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/usr/local/kannel'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define GW_NAME "Kannel"
#define GW_VERSION "1.4.3"
#define VERSION "1.4.3"

configure: exit 77
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be picking up the WinAVR compiler (which generates executables for the AVR instruction set) instead of the native compiler (which generates executables for i686). Try removing the WinAVR compiler from your path and see if that gets things working for you again.

If you actually do mean to build programs for the AVR, well then you need to specify a whole lot more information to configure to let it know to cross-compile. Getting things to successfully cross-compile with the GNU Autotools is an incredible pain and is never guaranteed to work. The following section of the Autotools book will explain the basics of how to use "configure" when cross-compiling if that is what you intend to do:

http://sources.redhat.com/autobook/autobook/autobook_258.html#SEC258